# Ubuntu 11.04 is not opening

Tags: 11.04

I am using Ubuntu 11.04 with Windows 7. Ubuntu was working nice but now when I choose Ubuntu 11.04 from boot loader, it is not opening. Just Purple screen is coming but then nothing change. I can't see login menu, it doesn't pass to the login menu. What should I do? Has anyone this problem?

---

Thanks for your answer. I did the steps you wrote **Frantique**. But now I have a black screen and then nothing. 
When I choosed ubuntu 11.04 from bootloader, first purple screen is opening then after 1 second it is going to a black screen. And I have nothing again. I can't write anything. Just I have a black screen. It is not openining.

---

Before those problems they work together nice. There aren't any errors. Lets I tell you what did I change: I installed docky, and theme of MACOSX. They were working nicely. And I tried to install a nice calendar. To do this installation I changed a litle bit the file sources.list. That calendar program was working succcesfully too, after installation. The theme MACOSX was working succesfully there weren't any problem. After some days maybe meeks I had that problem which I asked in the above. Now when I tried to update I have a lots of errors. Like:
Failed to urls...                      can't access archive something...
....
Failed to urls...                      can't access archive something...
....
.....
Failed to urls...                      can't access archive something...
I hope you will solve the problem. I want my MacOSXUbuntu back :)

Comment: Sorry for that. Did u make any upgrade or changes to Ubuntu? How was your system working before? Were u initially running both systems at the same time? We need more Info to study that

Comment: You can continue to edit your question by registering your account - in that way you wont have to keep creating new accounts when your browser cookie is lost.

Comment: are you able to access virtual terminal by pressing Ctrl + Alt + F1? Do this after you get stuck at black/blue screen.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, log in there and issue the following commands:

```
sudo killall Xorg  
mv -v ~/.config/compiz-1 ~/.config/compiz-1.BAD  
mv -v ~/.config/dconf ~/.config/dconf.BAD
```

After that press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>, and try to log in.